# Displaying values in one column as multiple columns

Tags: oracle, snowflake

I have a table which millions of records like this:

[image]

The desired format of the data is this:

[image]

how do i achieve this? tried a cross join but didnt help.
pivot is taking too long to execute as the dataset is huge.

Comment: Which database system and version are you using?

Comment: Im using snowflake. Btw I tried the query with case, but it’s pulling up only null values for the amt field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any cross join.

in SQL, you can write statement like this

```
select JD_WS_CD || '_' || JD_WS_SUB_CD || '_' || JD_SHP_TO, 
case when YM='202301' then AMT1 end as JAN_AMT1,
case when YM='202302' then AMT1 end as FEB_AMT1,
case when YM='202303' then AMT1 end as MAR_AMT1
FROM table
...
```

in excel,

```
First Column =A2 & "_" & B2& "_" & C2
JAN_AMT1 Column =IF(D2=202301;E2;"")
FEB_AMT1 Column =IF(D2=202302;E2;"")
MAR_AMT1 Column =IF(D2=202303;E2;"")
```

Comment: Yes, but like I said the dataset is huge. I’ve shown only a tiny portion of the data for illustration purposes. Using cases for each of them will not be possible.

Comment: This is returning nulls for the amt columns btw